# How to work with multiple Azure accounts with Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, centos7, account, azure-cli

my OS is centos 7, I'm working with Azure Cli, and I have multiple accounts, to change the default subscription, it must be done with this command:
az account set --subscription "My Demos"
but, for me, we have like multiple users, and foreach user an account, so a subscription-ID, if I used the command set it and the next user did the same, it will be a mess, so I want a solution to work with multiple accounts like amazon cli they got --profile.

Comment: Are you asking how you handle multiple users logging in to Subscriptions? Each user would login using their credentials `az login` and they can then set the Subscription and they will be operating under the Subscription they specify. Does that help?